# HTML: Word-Wrap not supporting

Tags: css, html

From below html code I want to show complete table in page without horizontal scrollbar. I want to set html table width fit to screen. there is continuous text in td which I want to break and show in multiple lines such that table width will not go out of page.

For that I used word wrap property but it will not work. Please suggest me possible solution.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="table-layout:fixed;">
         <tr>
            <td style="word-wrap:break-word;">jhdjhfjsjkfhjshdjfhjshfsbfsjkshdfjhsfjsdfdfjsndjkfnjsdnfsdfnsdjfnnsdjfnsdjnfjsdnf,sdnmfksdfsdfsdfsdnfklsdmklfmsdfsd,fsdfsdkfksdnmfnmsdkfnmsdmfmdfmd,.mf,dmf,msd,fm,sdmf,.smd,.fms,dmfms,dmf,s.dmf,.smdf,.smd,fmsdfm,.sdm,f.sdm,f.msd,.fms,.dmf,.sdmf,.sdmf,.smd,.fmsd,mf,.sdmf,.smd,.fmsd,.fm,sdmf,msd,.fms,.dmf,.sdmf,.sdmfsdmfsdf,.sdf,sdfsdfsdfsdf</td>  
            <td style="word-wrap:break-word;">jhdjhfjsjkfhjshdjfhjshfsbfsjkshdfjhsfjsdfdfjsndjkfnjsdnfsdfnsdjfnnsdjfnsdjnfjsdnf,sdnmfksdfsdfsdfsdnfklsdmklfmsdfsd,fsdfsdkfksdnmfnmsdkfnmsdmfmdfmd,.mf,dmf,msd,fm,sdmf,.smd,.fms,dmfms,dmf,s.dmf,.smdf,.smd,fmsdfm,.sdm,f.sdm,f.msd,.fms,.dmf,.sdmf,.sdmf,.smd,.fmsd,mf,.sdmf,.smd,.fmsd,.fm,sdmf,msd,.fms,.dmf,.sdmf,.sdmfsdmfsdf,.sdf,sdfsdfsdfsdf</td>  
         </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table (and by further extension, the cells) has no constriction, meaning it will stretch to fit around the content within it, so there is no reason for your words to be broken.

Try giving your table a width:

```
table{
    width:100%;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wovphnsa/)

Answer (score 0):

To use `style="word-wrap: break-word;` you have to fix the outer tag width.

```
table{
     width:100%;
}
```